# Save FrameLayout and childs in the a one bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-framelayout

I have this layout and try save the FrameLayout and all childs in the one Bitmap. The getDrawingCache not return the Bitmap. I try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534247/converting-framelayout-as-bitmap) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980732/saving-frame-layout-as-bitmap-with-its-subviews-but-imageviewsubview-giving-bl) and not work.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageOne"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/image2"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    imageOne.buildDrawingCache();
    imageTwo.buildDrawingCache();
    flPhoto.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    flPhoto.buildDrawingCache();

    mergedPhoto = flPhoto.getDrawingCache();

    String pathSavedBitmapFile = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mergedPhoto, "", null);
    flPhoto.destroyDrawingCache();
```

Comment: Do you have permissions in your AndroidManifest for writing file?

Comment: Oh yes, yes! The error in the line mergedPhoto = flPhoto.getDrawingCache();, mergedPhoto is always null.